# How is called the color which is the combination of yellow and orange in English?

Tags: word-request

In my language (spanish) this color is called amarillo huevo ("egg yellow") which is a clear contrast to amarillo patito ("little duck yellow"). How is called the color which is the combination of yellow and orange in English?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A survey found these colour names: for "bright" colours: Your colour is near the left side, at the yellow and orange border.

[image: chart of the dominant color names for the fully saturated faces of the RGB cube]

So, in general terms your colour is a "Yellow" or a "Yellow-orange".

There are several secondary colour names that name a similar colour:

[Saffron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saffron_(color)) (named after the spice)
[Ochre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ochre)  (named after a type of clay)
[Amber](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amber_(color)) (Fossilied pine resin)
[Mustard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_(color)) (a spice)

And some proprietary names: your colour is similar to [Sunglow](http://www.crayola.com/explore-colors/sunglow.aspx) by Crayola. (found by an [online tool](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color)

You will generate minimum confusion if you just say "yellow-orange" or "yellowish orange", but any of the other secondary colour names could also be used.

Colour words in English fall into roughly three groups. Main colours like "Red", "Black", "Brown": These are words that mean the colour, and other uses are secondary to the colour meaning. "Orange" is probably in this group, even though it was named after the fruit. These words can be combined to indicate a combination for example "Green-yellow"

Then there are words like "Teal", "Olive", which name a colour after an object.

Finally there are specific proprietary names used by painters and other colour workers. These names don't have much use outside this realm. For example, dulux use "Rising sap" for a green-yellow paint.

Comment: When I was a kid, my dad decorated our house, and painted the skirting boards and some of the other woodwork what I called 'green'. Oh no. It was eau-de-nil. I still hate that shade today.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can think of off the top of my head is

> ocher [US spelling], ochre [British spelling]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how precise you want to be, "Egg Yellow" or "Egg Yolk Yellow" works in English as well.

For example,

[image: Egg Yolk Yellow (1235C)]  <sup>Egg Yolk Yellow (1235C)</sup>

[image: Rosco E-Colour+ #768 Egg Yolk Yellow (48" x 25') Roll]   <sup>Rosco E-Colour+ #768 Egg Yolk Yellow (48" x 25') Roll</sup>

[image: Egg Yellow CK Squeeze Gel Food Color]  <sup>Egg Yellow CK Squeeze Gel Food Color</sup>

Color names are a tricky business. Even when we use the name of something that everyone is familiar with, like "egg yolk yellow", it only gives us a general idea of the color because of [natural variations in the saturation and brightness](http://eggtester.com/products/dsm-yolk-color-fan). Different color names like "ochre" or "mustard" can mean different things to different people and you should reference a color system like [Pantone](https://www.pantone.com/color-systems/pantone-color-systems-explained) if you want to be precise.

For example, "ochre" in the Pantone system has a wide range of colors from yellowish to deep red.

[image: PANTONE ocher color swatch]